# Strange autocompletion happening in Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios

When I update the Xcode to 7.3,something strange happens.

[image]

How can I fix it ?

Comment: in viewWillAppear set it to NO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much simpler in swift, just do this:

```
static let sharedMenu = KxMenu()
```